# Javascript change css top property

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi I'm trying to change background gradually on button click on my web page this is a javascript and html code snippets what am I doing wrong?

```
var content=document.getElementById('content').style;
var content1 = document.getElementById('content1').style;
var start1;
var start2;
var inti =null; 
function changeContent(){       
    start1 =1;
    start2 = 1001;  
    inti=setInterval('swapContent()',20);       
}

function swapContent(){  
    start1 -=5;
    start2 -=5;
    content.top = start1 + 'px';
    content1.top = start2 + 'px';                        
} 

 <body>

    <div id="navigation" >
    <input type="button" onclick="changeContent()" />
    </div>
    <div id="content">
    </div>
    <div id="content1">
    </div>        
</body>
```

Comment: In what way does the code not work? (Also, don't call `setInterval` with a string, and ideally don't call Javascript with HTML attributes...)

Comment: positions of the content doesn't change

Comment: Why not use CSS transitions, that's what they're for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want style `top` to work, you should set css position property. [See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kbknt/)

Comment: I have set position attribute too absolute